# Creating Nested Query in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am totally new to Spring Data Elasticsearch and trying to build a query like the one below;
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 {
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "bool":{
                  "should":[
                     {
                        "match_phrase":{
                           "firstPhrase":"A"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match_phrase":{
                           "secondPhrase":"B"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "nested":{
                           "path":"things",
                           "query":{
                              "bool":{
                                 "should":[
                                    {
                                       "match_phrase":{
                                          "another.phraseOne":"C"
                                       }
                                    },
                                    {
                                       "match_phrase":{
                                          "another.phraseTwo":"D"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "match_phrase":{
                  "otherPhase":"E"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I started with creating the first two boolean queries;

```
BoolQueryBuilder firstBool = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("firstPhrase", "A"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("secondPhrase", "B"));

BoolQueryBuilder secondBool = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("another.phraseOne", "C"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("another.phraseTwo", "D"));
```

Then I tried to create a nested query (Not sure how to use ScoreMode);

```
 QueryBuilder nestedQuery= nestedQuery("things",secondBool, ScoreMode.None);
```

I created another match-phrase which is in the must;

```
 QueryBuilder third = QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("otherPhrase", "E");
```

I am not sure how to add them all to create the structure I have and most importantly not sure how to add the nested query to the "must".

```
  QueryBuilder allQueries = new BoolQueryBuilder()
            .must(first)
            .must(second)
            .must(third);
```

And finally, using them all at once;

```
NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(allQueries).build();
```

Would this be a right approach to achive what I am trying to generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, rearranging the order of querybuilding:

```java
import org.apache.lucene.search.join.ScoreMode;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BoolQueryBuilder boolShouldCD = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("another.phraseOne", "C"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("another.phraseTwo", "D"));

        QueryBuilder nestedQuery= QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("things",boolShouldCD, ScoreMode.None);

        BoolQueryBuilder boolShouldABNested = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("firstPhrase", "A"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("secondPhrase", "B"))
                .should(nestedQuery);

        QueryBuilder allQueries = new BoolQueryBuilder()
                .must(boolShouldABNested)
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchPhraseQuery("otherPhrase", "E"));

        System.out.println(allQueries.toString());
    }
}
```

This is plain Elasticsearch client code, to use that in Spring Data Elasticsearch using the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder` is the right way to go.

---

After inlining and static imports you get this shorter code:

```java
import org.apache.lucene.search.join.ScoreMode;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder;

import static org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        QueryBuilder allQueries = new BoolQueryBuilder()
                .must(boolQuery()
                        .should(matchPhraseQuery("firstPhrase", "A"))
                        .should(matchPhraseQuery("secondPhrase", "B"))
                        .should(nestedQuery("things", boolQuery()
                                .should(matchPhraseQuery("another.phraseOne", "C"))
                                .should(matchPhraseQuery("another.phraseTwo", "D")), ScoreMode.None)))
                .must(matchPhraseQuery("otherPhrase", "E"));

        System.out.println(allQueries.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @P.J.Meisch. The shorter version looks very elegant. Do you mean the way I specified the edited NativeSearchQueryBuilder at the end is the right way? Thanks

Comment: Using `NativeSearchQuery` always gives you the possibility to build the most complex queries with Elasticsearch's classes and then pass them to Spring Data Elasticsearch. And yes, you have a query instance the to pass to the `ElasticsearchOperations.search(...)` methods.